# Is there a point of wearing a talis that does not require tzitzis?

Tags: tzitzis, tallit-gadol, borrowing

There is a din in the gemorah (Chullin [110a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=31&daf=110&format=pdf)/[110b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=31&daf=110b&format=pdf) and likely elsewhere)

> ואמר רב יהודה טלית שאולה כל שלשים יום פטורה מן הציצית
>
> A borrowed tallis does not require tzitzis for 30 days (my paraphrase)

(and therefore many have a custom not to recite a blessing on a borrowed tallis). If, say, I am praying shacharis with a borrowed tallis and tfilin, is there any point in wearing the tallis?

Comment: mipnei kavod hatzibur (for the sake of the respect of the congregation)?

Comment: There is a diffrence between a patur beged and a beged that  is mechuyav for one person and not for another(borrowed tallis)

Comment: Also there is an inyun of kavod habrioyos when one would be embarresed even if the tallis is pasul one may wear details should be learnt in the mishna brurah.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the citation. I see what you're talking about now.

Comment: @SethJ Im sorry for the error I hope I didn't waste your time

Comment: A quick search of Yabia Omer for the phrase "טלית שאולה" brings up a whole bunch of teshuvot. Several even address this question: see for example Yabia Omer O"C 9:81:8. perhaps someone will take the time to write up an answer from there.

Comment: Hahu Gavra, not at all. I found it. And I learned something.

Answer (score 3):

The Shulchan Aruch rules (OC 14:3) that even though a man is exempt from attaching tzitzit to a borrowed four-cornered garment, if he borrowed it with tzitzit already attached, then he may say a blessing on it, implying that there is a mitzva that happens when he wears (at least a reshut--voluntary mitzva). So it would seem like there is good reason to wear that kind of tallit during prayers.

Comment: Thats the shulchan aruchs opinion. My custom is otherwise- I do not make a brucha on a tallis sheula unless it belongs to a shul and is designated to be borrowed. I even included that info in the question for this very reason.

Comment: @HahuGavra You did not include that info (nor does it particularly matter what _your_ practice is, as none of this is lemaaseh). You said that some do and some don't. You don't specify who holds what, and according to which side the question is. As it is now, you don't even verify that either of those sides is a real opinion and not a mistake. My answer stands.

Answer (score 3):

A טלית is not necessarily a "prayer shawl" as commonly associated today. The word refers to a four-cornered wrap, like a toga, or a cape. Although it previously mentioned Tefillin the Gemara could talking about a generic cape/wrap/shawl, not a "prayer shawl" as often thought of today.

On the other hand, it seems like (ahem) "Hahu Gavra" was being sort of a trouble-maker, so it's possible he didn't care about anything other than making a point.

Comment: I dont see how this answers perhaps you can clarify...

Comment: The citation was correct; you looked at Chulin 101 while Hahu Gavra asked about Chulin 110 (which does contain the quote, at the very bottom of the daf).

Comment: @ba, Yes, see new edit. The link did not work for me. The citation was originally 101, not 110.

Comment: @HahuGavra, hopefully this helps. Also, no offense - the last line is tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: @SethJ would the laws of something being chayav in tzitzis be different depending on its use? whether its a cloak or a prayer shawl, if it does not require tzitzis, do you fulfill a mitzvah by wearing it? From what i understand the POINT of wearing a prayer shawl is to fulfill the mitzvah of tzitzis, which isn't necessarily happening here.

Comment: @SethJ Hahu Gavra is more of a troublemaker than you'd guess

Comment: @hahugavra, you're asking if there's any point in wearing a shawl without strings. Yes. If you're cold.